# How do I check what version of Java I have installed?

Tags: windows, java, version

I want to check what version of Java is installed on my PC before installing the latest Java update. How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can check your version of Java with any of the following methods.

---

### Java Control Panel (*Windows*)

1. Open the **Start Menu** and select **Control Panel**.
2. From the Control Panel, select **Programs -> Java** to open the **Java Control Panel**.

[image: Control Panel -> Programs -> Java]

3. Select **About** to view your current version of Java.

[image: Java version from Java Control Panel]

---

### Command Line (*Windows*)

1. Press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type **cmd** to open the **Command Prompt**.

[image: Opening CMD with Run tool]

2. Type `java -version` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Java version from command line]

---

### Control Panel (*Windows*)

***Note***: This method may give inaccurate results if Java's PATH has not been updated.

1. Open the **Start Menu** and select **Control Panel**.
2. From the Control Panel, select **Programs -> Programs and Features**.
3. Scroll down the list of programs until you find the most recently installed version of Java

[image: Java version from Windows Control Panel]

---

### Terminal (*MacOS*)

1. In the **Finder**, search for **Terminal** and launch **Terminal.app**

[image: Searching for Terminal.app in Finder]

2. Type `java -version` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Java version in MacOS terminal]

---

#### Sources

- [Tech FAQ - How to Check the Java Version](http://www.tech-faq.com/how-to-check-my-java-version.html)
- [Columbia - How to check what Java version you have](http://www.c2b2.columbia.edu/danapeerlab/html/Genatomy/java.pdf)

Comment: These methods show different versions even on the same machine. Some say v7.0, some say v1.7...

Comment: @mblakesley: that's not a difference; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411288/java-versioning-and-terminology-1-6-vs-6-0-openjdk-vs-sun especially the second-high-voted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2411663/2868801 . For the 'modular' versions j9 up, starting in 2017, they finally dropped the '1.' prefix.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open CMD (In Windows click Start then type cmd, Command Prompt or PowerShell) and execute the following commands.
2. For multiple java installations: `wmic product where "name like 'Java%'" get name, version`
3. For default java installation: `java -version`

Answer (score 2):

The methods below will help you to check the [Java version](https://orahow.com/check-java-version-installed-on-linux/) in Linux:

- `ps -ef|grep -i JAVA`
- `java -version`
- `which java`

Answer (score 1):

In windows
open command prompt using cmd

Then, type the command java -version

Then, click enter. You will see your java version

Comment: You're correct. However, this answer has been posted already by another user.

Answer (score 0):

Checking Java version on Windows PowerShell, simply use the command:

```bsh
java -version
```

Be careful there is only one dash in the command to be run.